# Gabber purity theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, etale-cohomology

Given a closed immersion $i :Z \hookrightarrow X$ of regular noetherian schemes, of pure codimension $c$. Let $\Lambda$ be the locally constant sheaf $Z/nZ$ and assume $n$ is invertible on $X$. Gabber purity tells us when the following morphism of etale cohomology groups

$H^{r-2c}(Z, \Lambda (-c)) \rightarrow H_{Z}^{r}(X, \Lambda)$

is an isomorphism, where $\Lambda (-c)$ is the tensor product of sheaf of the $n^{th}$ roots of unity $c$ times, for $c < 0$ and for $c > 0$, one takes the dual.
I know the existence of above isomorphism in following cases

1. $X$ and $Y$ are smooth over a field $k$.
2. $X$ is a local ring of dimension 1 and $Y$ is the closed point.

I want to know if the theorem is more generally true. I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ is a local ring of any dimension greater than 1 and $Y$ is the closed point or in fact any other closed scheme (need not be smooth).

P.S  (There is another way of stating this theorem in terms of right derived functors of $i^!$, which I have eschewed.)

Comment: It seems the theorem is true in general. See "A Proof of the Absolute Purity Conjecture (after Gabber)" by Fujiwara

Comment: @AlexL are you referring to the case when $X$ is of equal characteristic? Otherwise it's not generally true.

Comment: Look at Theorem 2.1.1 of the paper

Comment: Thanks, you are right.